# Solve the inequality $(1/2)^x-(1/2)^{-1-x}\ge1$ for real $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

I have to solve in $\Bbb{R}$ the following inequality :

> $$
> \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1 - x} \ge 1  \qquad(E)
> $$

So far I have :

For $x=0$  this inequality if not true. Writting $a^x=\exp(x\log(a))$ $(E)$ can be written 
$$
2^{-x}-2^{1+x}\ge1
$$

I tried to factor but I do not get a friendly solution, and then I tried to study :
$$
{\rm f}\left(x\right)=2^{-x}-2^{1+x}
$$
I have ${\rm f}'\left(x\right)=2^{-x}(1+2^{1+2 x})\log(2)$ wich is stricly negative for all $x$, and so ${\rm f}$ is decreasing.

We have ${\rm f}\left(x\right) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$ and ${\rm f}\left(-1\right)=1$ then the inequality is correct only for $x \le 1$.

I think it's correct ( ? ) but do you think this can be solved without using the derivative ?.

Comment: Why the dowvote I think it's clear and and shows research effort.

Comment: Fractions $\frac12$ are fine in text, but in question titles the vertical dimension should be minimized as much as possible:  tall titles break question lists. I changed to $1/2$ in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take up things when you reached $2^{-x}-2^{1+x}\ge 1$. Multiply through by $2^x$, and rearrange a bit. We get $2\cdot 2^{2x}+2^x-1\ge 0$.  Rewrite as $(2^x+1)(2\cdot 2^x-1)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: transform the inequality to a quadratic inequality with the substitution $y = 2^x$, then $2^{-x} = \dfrac{1}{y}$

Comment: Very simple indeed..and nice hint. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't realise you posted (on my phone) so deleted it with that in hindsight :). +1

Comment: You can repost it, as I think you also got good point there....

Comment: It is ok, the OP understands it from here. If you wanted to edit it to be more explicit then it's best from this one answer than mine :).

Comment: In fact I have a question, i have $2y^2+y-1\le 0$ to solve, i get $(y+1)(2y-1)\le 0$ then the inegqulity is correct for $y\in (-1,1/2)$ right? How can I continue?

Comment: @Yass remember that $y>0$.

Comment: @Chinny84 Can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: @Yass $2^x>0\,\,\forall x$ where x is a real (I can not remember the element symbol)